# Conditional replacement in a string

Tags: python, string

I have two strings s1 and s2

I want to replace all character in s1 which do not appear in s2 to a special character, let's say "+"

For instance,

```
s1 = "abc"
s2 = "bc" # "a" does not appear in s2
--> output = "+bc"
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) along with a ternary operator

```
>>> s1 = "abc"
>>> s2 = "bc"
>>> "".join(i if i in s2 else '+' for i in s1)
'+bc'
```

The logic here is that you loop through the string to check if each of the character is present in the other string. If it is not present then you replace it with `+`.